# Google Script: How to make a cursor move to the next row in column A

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to make an Entry/Exit logbook, where staff would tag their ID cards to the card-reader at the entrance, which will populate a cell in column A, and this will trigger the script to create a day/time stamp.

```
{
function activeSheetName() 
  {
return
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName();
}
{
var timezone = "GMT+7";
  var timestamp_format = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"; // Timestamp Format.
var updateColName = "CardID";
var timeStampColName = "Date/Time";
var sheet = event.source.getSheetByName('Current'); //Name of the sheet where you want to run this script.

var actRng = event.source.getActiveRange();
var actSheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
var actSheetName = actSheet.getSheetName();
var updateSheetName = sheet.getSheetName();
var editColumn = actRng.getColumn();
var index = actRng.getRowIndex();
var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
var dateCol = headers[0].indexOf(timeStampColName);
var updateCol = headers[0].indexOf(updateColName); updateCol = updateCol+1;
if (dateCol > -1 && index > 1 && editColumn == updateCol && actSheetName == updateSheetName) { // only timestamp if ‘Last Updated’ header exists, but not in the header row itself!
var cell = sheet.getRange(index, dateCol + 1);
var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, timestamp_format);
cell.setValue(date);
}
}
}
```

The problem is when the card is tagged, the cursor stays in the cell, so I need to hit enter for it to move down. Can I edit the script above for cursor to move one cell down automatically, as soon as the ID card is read by the reader? Please help, I've tried a separate jump down script and edit this one, but nothing worked so far. Thanks!

[Example Logbook](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14Qehm5hQICKxFJX1NRm3hwdCAQP42iMCPG4rdsQjmQo/edit#gid=270722014)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean mouse cursor, then I don't think you can do it via GAS. But if I understand you correctly, you want to activate the next cell in Column A after value was set. To do that,  add method `sheet.getRange(index+1,1).activate();` after you set value.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I've added it, but unfortunately it didn't work. And yes - I mean a mouse cursor. Maybe it's impossible as you suggest. Thanks anyways.